# Fiddles: Lista de páginas que podemos usar para probar código y sus características

Tags: discusión, recursos

Muchas veces usamos probadores de código en línea tales como jsfiddle, rextester, phpfiddle, sqlfiddle, etc.

Son muy útiles, y mejoran nuestras respuestas en SO.

Propongo crear una lista con los enlaces a tales páginas, en la que se indique las características principales de cada una.

Por ejemplo:

- [`phpfiddle`](http://phpfiddle.org/): Código PHP incluyendo conexiones a bases de datos
- <s>javafiddle</s>: Código Java incluyendo conexiones a bases de datos

(La segunda opción, sueño con que un día exista).

¿Qué les parece la idea?

---

> **Nota importante:**
>
> No compartamos enlaces que no sean útiles para enriquecer nuestras
>   respuestas en SO. Los IDEs en línea cuyo enlace final para compartir
>   sea generado por un acortador de enlaces como go.gl, bitly u otros, no
>   será aceptado por SO, por motivos de seguridad.

Comment: No es por evitar tal listado, pero aquí hay un listado muy completo de ides en linea https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

Comment: Que parece si a esta pregunta...ya que hablamos de codigo y ello, no adjuntamos un par de enlaces de sitios que indentan el codigo (*code beautify*)? Digo, ahi muchas preguntas donde se pone el codigo, se formatea con *ctrl + K* y la dejan asi, como quede...Creo que podriamos agregar un par de enlaces, o que piensan al respecto?

Comment: @IvanBotero creo que se podría crear una respuesta para lo que propones, o bien crear un apartado dentro de la misma respuesta ya existente. Pero hay quienes han considerado que no conviene tener una respuesta demasiado larga.

Comment: tutorialspoint pide que te registres para compartir el código. Desde mi punto de vista no debería estar en la lista, ya que lo que busco (¿y buscamos? me imagino..) es probar/modificar/compartir el código de forma rápida y sin realizar pasos extras. ¿Qué opinan?

Comment: @MatiasOlivera No, yo puedo compartir sin registrarme.

Comment: @A.Cedano Quisiera decir, que esos enlaces acortados de tutorialspoint, si ingreso a un enlace acortado, me redirige al enlace real, el cual se puede compartir: Ejemplo: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMT1I4X2dOcnhYSm8

Comment: @MatiasOlivera: En [tutorialspoint.com/codingground](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm) se permite compartir código (sin previo registro), únicamente, en la sección **Online IDEs**. En las secciones **Document Editors** y **Front-end Technologies** puedes compartir proyecto, pero previo registro. En la sección **Online Terminals** no es posible compartir ni código ni proyecto.

Comment: @ArtEze quiero decir que cuando pulsas en _Sharcode_, tutorialspoint genera una url parecia a esta: https://goo.gl/R5j9Af   Ese tipo de URLs son bloqueadas en esSO por motivos de seguridad.

Comment: @A.Cedano Bueno, ahora entiendo tu punto... Aunque es posible compartirlo, redirigiendo anteriormente, es problemático el botón compartir no permite acceder directamente al enlace.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### I. Lenguajes específicos

### .Net

- [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net): Permite los lenguajes C#,Vb.NET y F#
- [csharppad.com](https://www.csharppad.com): C#

#### C++

- [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php)
- [cpp.sh](https://cpp.sh/)
- [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)
- [ideone](https://ideone.com/)

### Elasticsearch

- [Found](https://www.found.no/play)

### Go

- [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/)

#### HTML/JavaScript/CSS

- [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net)
- [codepen](https://codepen.io/)
- [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
- [Glitch](https://glitch.com/) excelente sevidor **node js**, online :) (de algunos los creadores de Stack Overflow)
- [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) Angular, React entre otros y permite en tiempo real colaboración en código
- [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/): un completo entorno de desarrollo, fork de Visual Studio Code, que permite importar proyectos de Github y trabaja con proyectos de Angular, React, Vue... usando Javascript o Typescript. Incluye una ventana que simula un navegador para ver en tiempo real el resultado del código

#### Node.js

- [RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/): Entorno de desarrollo, en navegador, para prototipar código Node.js
- [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/): VS Code, en navegador, para Angular, React y Ionic

#### PHP

- [phpfiddle.org](https://phpfiddle.org): Incluye posibilidad de probar consultas a bases de datos
- [OnlinePHPFunctions](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) (Sandbox PHP)
- [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/) se puede usar HHVM.

#### Python

- [Python-3x](https://repl.it/languages/python3)
- [Python-2x](https://repl.it/languages/python2)
- [PythonFiddle](https://pythonfiddle.com/)

#### R

- [r-fiddle.org](https://www.r-fiddle.org/#/)

#### Expresiones Regulares (Regex):

- [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)
- [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/) → Se puede visualizar los nodos de la ER (*Se tiene la opción de compartir a SO imagen y enlace*)
- [ReFiddle](https://refiddle.com/)
- [regexr.com](https://regexr.com): Con documentación para el aprendizaje sobre expresiones regulares y su funcionamiento.

#### Ruby

- [RubyFiddle](https://rubyfiddle.com/)

#### Scala

- [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/)

#### Shell scripting

- [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) → analiza el código de Bash y shell detectando irregularidades y recomendando mejores prácticas.

#### SQL

- [sqlfiddle.com](https://www.sqlfiddle.com): muy bueno, aunque a veces no funciona. La función markdown es genial.
- [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)
- [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

#### Swift

- [IBM Swift Sandbox](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/)

---

### II. Multilenguaje

- [rextester.com](https://rextester.com): Multitud de lenguajes y también bases de datos. Menos publicidad que ideone.
- [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/): Multitud de lenguajes (java,python anyone?)
- [code.runnable.com](https://code.runnable.com/) : Multitud de lenguajes (C++, Java, C#, etc.)
- [repl.it](https://repl.it/): Multitud de lenguajes (Python, Ruby, Go, Java, C, PHP, etc.)
- [codeshare.io](https://codeshare.io/): Compartir codigo en vivo
- [Try It Online (TIO)](https://tio.run/): Familia de intérpretes en línea para una cada vez mayor lista de lenguajes de programación prácticos y recreativos.
- [fiddles.io](https://fiddles.io/): Página que recopila fiddles.
- [jdoodle.com](https://www.jdoodle.com/): Multitud de lenguajes ( 60+ lenguajes )

  ---

### <s>III. Soñar no cuesta nada</s>

Lo que te gustaría que fuera y (por ahora) no es

- javafiddle
- pythonfiddle

Los sueños se hacen realidad: https://ideone.com/ soporta (a fecha 13 de Julio de 2017):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias. Para no tener varias respuestas ¿se podría tener una sola que sea wiki de comunidad, la cual se vaya editando?

Comment: ¿Cómo ven si separamos cada tema en respuestas independientes? Es decir, tener una para lenguajes específicos, otra para multilenguajes, y otra más para "la lista de deseos"

Comment: A mi me parece bien @Rubén, si la lista crece mucho estaría mejor organizada

Comment: Hace mucho que no veo números romanos.

Comment: Excellent compendio! ;)

Comment: Excelente recopilación