# Recomendar agregar un create de ejemplo en las preguntas de base de datos

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, estado-completado, preguntas, advertencias-en-preguntas

Vi varias preguntas sobre bases de datos donde no se agregan las ddl, ni siquiera un create de las tablas que se utilizan.

Esto seria de mucha ayuda a la hora de tratar de ayudar a alguien a arreglar sus querys, o siquiera de como armarlos, sobre todo aprovechando la cantidad de fiddles que hay para eso mismo.

Por lo tanto propongo que ante cada pregunta sobre base de datos, se le recomiende al Usuario de ser posible que agregue el create de las tablas y un pequeño diagrama de las mismas, siempre que esto sea posible.

(esto me surge por la siguiente pregunta [Seleccionar registros según correlativos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91573/seleccionar-registros-seg%C3%BAn-correlativos))

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Tendrían que agregar a la pregunta tanto las sentencias para la creación de las tablas como una cantidad razonable de inserciones, para hacer que las pruebas sean lo más cercanas posibles al modelo original.

Comment: @gbianchi: La etiqueta [meta-tag:característica-nueva] es para cambios en en los algoritmos o interfaz de usuario del sistema. ¿Cuál es el cambio y a qué elemento en particular se refiere? Por otro lado, usualmente sólo se usa una de las etiquetas obligatorias: o es discusión o es propuesta de característica nueva o se solicita soporte o se hace un reporte de bug. En casos como este hilo, podríamos decir que primero se hace uno para discutir y luego otro para hacer la propuesta. Por cierto, sí, ya vi que fedorqui propuso agregar la etiqueta, pero obviamente pienso diferente :D

Comment: A esta altura con que uno de los nuevos mods se haga cargo de esto, para el lado que quieran, me da lo mismo :p @Rubén.. y yo lo agregaria con un mvce distinto, para preguntas de base de datos...

Comment: Nótese que esto finalmente se implementó en [Advertencias en preguntas potencialemente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>Estuve pendiente de los comentarios a la [respuesta de gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2598/83), que comparto. Como quiero incluir una imagen, prefiero continuar el debate con una publicación en toda regla</sub>

Apoyo la moción. Creo que es útil y, de hecho, ya se hace en SOen cuando se [formula una pregunta con la etiqueta SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=sql):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En efecto, en ese momento aparece una [descripción emergente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20159/1674) (*tooltip*, vaya) con esta información:

> SQL questions get better answers if they...
>   - Include a tag for one specific database engine (MySQL, Oracle, etc...)
>   - Show the SQL that isn't working
>   - Describe exactly how it isn't working (error message, unexpected results, etc...)
>   - Describe the desired results

Sugiero que se adapte el mismo comportamiento, adaptando el texto a nuestro sitio y posiblemente incluyendo un enlace a la [página de Fiddles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/83) como referencia. Así, se podría dejar un texto del tipo:

> Las preguntas de SQL reciben mejores respuestas si...
>   - Incluyen una etiqueta de gestor de bases de datos específico (MySQL, Oracle...)
>   - Muestran el SQL que no funciona.
>   - Describen exactamente en qué no funcionan (mensaje de error, resultados no esperados...)
>   - Describen cuáles son los resultados esperados.
>   - Explican porque se tiene ese modelo de datos (en los casos de modelos no normalizados).
>   - Incluyen el modelo de datos.
>   - Adicionalmente, un [Fiddle de ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/83) resulta muy útil para reproducir el error y poder *jugar* con los datos. Si no, un create de las tablas para poder generarlas.

Comment: Esta idea me cuadra más, un tooltip en la etiqueta está bien y se puede poner en todas las que haga falta sin recargar la página de ayuda. Apoyo la moción

Comment: Hagamos un mix entre lo que dice el help en ingles y los datos que agregue yo, porque parece que la comunidad en español es mas vaga y necesita un empuje mas fuerte para algunas cosas...

Comment: @gbianchi siéntete libre de editar mi respuesta para añadir más datos en el texto tipo.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que propongo es modificar la pagina de ayuda

[mcve](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Agregando algo asi como:

> Problemas sobre base de datos:
>
> Agrega a tu pregunta la siguiente información:
>
> - Un listado de las tablas involucradas con sus relaciones (no es necesario que esten todos los campos, pero si aquellos que influyen en
>     el resultado)
> - Un pequeño set de datos de ejemplo
> - El resultado que obtuviste
> - El resultado que esperabas obtener
> - Un create de las tablas con insert de datos.
> - El caso de uso que explique el porque se tiene ese modelo de tablas (para recomendar normalizacion o no recomendarla, según corresponda

No se si corresponde a la pagina que mencione, o si es necesario tener una nueva pagina de ayuda para esto.

Comment: En algunas ocasiones, es necesario que el OP explique cúal es el caso de estudio y por qué razón llego finalmente al modelo actual. ¿Por qué? Para evitar, en la medida de lo posible, los errores de diseño en la base de datos por no seguir buenas prácticas (normalización) o por desconocimiento. [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91607/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-una-sola-b%c3%basqueda-consultando-diferentes-tablas-en-la-bd)

Comment: Mientras se revisa lo de modificar el [mcve] ¿Has considerado cuál etiqueta sería la más apropiada para este tipo de preguntas e incluir ahí la recomendación sobre incluir el create?

Comment: la etiqueta base-de-datos seria un gran primer candidato.. Sql tambien lo seria... Ahora hay muchas etiquetadas como la base de datos que corresponde solamente.. pero me pareceria un exceso ponerlo en todos lados..

Comment: Buena idea. Dado que es sugerencia, podrías añadir la etiqueta [meta-tag:característica-nueva] para que los moderadores la evalúen e implementen si lo consideran.

Comment: @fedorqui: ¿Apoyas en particular editar la página mcve o crear una nueva?

Comment: Yo no creo que se deba añadir en [mcve], cada lenguaje puede tener sus peculiaridades y la ayuda es general, quien pregunta debería valorar que información debe dar para su caso concreto.

Comment: @Rubén le di una vuelta al tema y publiqué una respuesta, pues se me quedaba corto aquí en los comentarios. Básicamente, mostrar un _tooltip_ con información recomendada al usar etiquetas de bases de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Otro ejemplo: [Lógica de query SQL o MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92053/l%C3%B3gica-de-query-sql-o-mysql)

Cómo no esta clara cuál es la estructura de la base de datos, todos los que quieren responderla terminan suponiendo cosas y basándose únicamente en la consulta SQL que aparece en la misma. Es claro que los que responden quieren ayudar, pero ¡es como si estuvieran jugando a los dardos con los ojos tapados!

Además, el OP da información relevante a cuentagotas en los comentarios en vez de editar la pregunta por lo que hay que leer todas las respuestas y los comentarios para tratar de entender cual es el resultado esperado.

Comment: Esta respuesta no responde la pregunta.No me queda claro si se está "abonando" a la descripción de la problemática planteada por el OP o por el contrario se está proponiendo esperar en lugar de solicitar un create.

Comment: @Rubén Solo quería dejar constancia de otra pregunta en donde se quiere ayudar pero no se cuenta con toda la información relevante. Edite la respuesta para que quede más claro.