# Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, preguntas, advertencias-en-preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

## Actualización: No voy a seguir monitoreando esta pregunta. No tengo claro cómo seguir aceptando solicitudes. Voy a conversar con los moderadores a ver qué nos queda mejor a todos.

El otro día, mientras agregaba [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) a la lista negra, descubrí que además de bloquear etiquetas, podemos mostrar advertencias.

Estas advertencias no evitan que alguien ponga una pregunta, pero aparecen como alertas para ayudar a los usuarios a hacer preguntas que tengan mejores probabilidades de no ser cerradas.

Se me ocurrió que podemos usarlas en preguntas con algunos términos que ya sabemos que son complicados... ¿qué les parece? Aparecerían así (y el texto lo podemos definir nosotros)

[image: advertencias]

Lo bueno es que, como podemos usar expresiones regulares, podemos hacer cosas como `mercado.?pago` y las tres instancias del ejemplo son reconocidas.

¿Lo hacemos? ¿Qué etiquetas tendrían sentido?

Para organizar el feedback sugeriría:

- Upvotes a esta pregunta quieren decir "sí, hagámoslo".
- Downvotes a esta pregunta quieren decir "no, me parece una mala idea".
- Respuestas a esta pregunta son sugerencias de etiquetas / textos problemáticos donde podríamos usar esta funcionalidad. **Si pueden incluir una expresión regular y un texto de ayuda, ¡genial!**
- Upvotes/downvotes a esas respuestas nos permiten priorizar y ver en qué términos tendría más sentido.

## Sugerencias implementadas

Voy borrando las respuestas que fueron implementadas para que las únicas que queden sean aquellas que necesitan feedback.

- SQL

  - Expresión regular: `^sql$`
  - Aplicada a: etiqueta
  - [Texto de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2zzw.png)
- Mercado Pago

  - Expresión regular: `mercado.?(pago|libre)`
  - Aplicada a: título, cuerpo de la pregunta, etiquetas
  - [Texto de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlB9H.png)
- Etiquetas [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error), [errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/errores) y cía.

  - Expresión regular: `^er+or[es]*$`
  - Aplicada a: etiquetas
  - [Texto de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apm4x.png)
- Etiquetas [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) y [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)

  - Expresión regular: `^angular(js)?[-.\d]*$`
  - Aplicada a: etiquetas
  - [Texto de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRUBv.png)
- Subida de código fuente como imágenes

  - Expresión regular: `i\.stack\.imgur\.com`
  - Aplicada a: cuerpo
  - [Texto de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF6Qo.png)
- Ayuda

  - Expresión regular: `ayuda`
  - Aplicada a: título
  - [Texto de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ullb.png)
- Python.* ([referencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4014/83))

  - Expresión regular: `python.*`
  - Aplicada a: etiquetas
  - [Texto de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVfGz.png)

Comment: Este hallazgo enamora

Comment: Bueno, bueno, bueno...que descubrimiento! Por supuesto que hay que aprovechar esta posibilidad! Aunque mi experiencia dice que aunque pongas carteles luminosos con avisos acusticos, los usuarios al final hacen lo que les da la gana, pero por intentarlo que no quede :)

Comment: @Pikoh No todos por suerte. Hay algunos que van con orejeras y da igual lo que les pongan pero otros leen las recomendaciones y hasta aprenden, para esos si sirven estas cosas.

Comment: Excelente lo de mostrar advertencias, ¿se podrá agregar el enlace de la compañia en cuestion?... hehe!

Comment: @Jorgesys no encontré ninguna advertencia que linkee a sitios externos... preferiría no agregarlo a no ser que tenga el ok de Juan

Comment: El pop-up este me salió en una respuesta. ¿Es eso normal o el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ouch! si, cuando lo aplicamos al cuerpo, se muestra tanto para las preguntas como para las respuestas (cosa que no sabía)... así que capaz que necesitamos ajustar los mensajes?

Comment: ¿El texto de la advertencia puede incluir enlaces?

Comment: @Rubén si :) creo que el de sql tiene

Comment: Se ve un recurso muy bueno para combatir la avalancha de preguntas "problemáticas" que se ve todos los días.

Comment: Relacionado: [Deleting suggestions posted as answers when they are implemented: Is this problematic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320524/289691)

Comment: @Rubén qué sentido tiene poner objecciones en Meta.SE a cómo se está tratando esta pregunta sin haberlo planteado antes aquí? Resulta un poco incomprensible, máxime teniendo en cuenta la amplia recepción de propuestas que siempre tiene g3rv4.

Comment: @fedorqui 1) El tema ya lo había planteado en Meta es.so en varias ocasiones en las que mi conclusión fue esperar a ver que pasa y antes de volverlo a plantear de nuevo me gustaría tener el punto de vista de los usuarios de Meta SE 2) Usé este caso como referencia pues es el que está activo esta semana  3) No solicité que se deshiciera la eliminación de respuestas ni la restauración de puntos 4) Gracias por publicar una repuesta allá.

Comment: g3rv4 ¿existe opción de retomar el tema? ¿Pudisteis comentarlo con los moderadores? Lo que expresó @Rubén entiendo que es tangencial pues la tarea en sí siempre depende de un empleado para ir añadiendo advertencias... y estaba yendo muy bien : )

Comment: te recomendaría que crees una pregunta en meta así la comunidad decide cómo proceder :) yo, mientras tenga una cola de cosas por hacer que pueda manejar yo (puede ser un board de trello, me pueden mandar mails, lo que sea) me sirve. Debería ser alguna opción con la que la comunidad se sienta cómoda. Si no encontramos una intersección entre esas dos, entonces yo me bajo :)

Comment: ahora vi @g3rv4 que me contestaste (ese `@` :P). Planteado en [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83)

Answer (score 14):

## Mercado Pago

**Expresión regular**: `mercado.?(pago|libre)`

**Aplicar a**: Todos (Título, cuerpo de la pregunta, etiquetas)

**Texto de ayuda**:

> Las preguntas técnicas son bienvenidas, pero aquellas sobre temas de servicio al cliente deben ser canalizadas directamente a Mercado Pago.

Comment: Como sugerencia, dejaría siempre bien claro que las preguntas que no cumplan estas recomendaciones terminarán cerradas. Por ejemplo: "Las preguntas que no cumplan con esta recomendación seguramente serán cerradas por la comunidad".

Comment: Ojo, MercadoPago directamente canaliza las preguntas hacia aquí, tal y como se ha indicado repetidamente en este Meta y muy bien resumido en [¿Se debería hacer algo en particular con el caso de MercadoPago?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3073/83). Si por ejemplo entras en https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/community/, te dirigen directamente a la etiqueta [tag:mercadopago]. Por tanto, __urge que el CM se ponga en contacto con ellos para terminar con este ping pong tan cansino y contraproducente para los usuarios__, pues da una imagen bastante mala de ambos sitios, MP y SOes.

Comment: Podriamos agregar de igual manera  a  Woocommerce, tal como se dijo aqui: [¿Por qué se deniega soporte a Woocommerce?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2949/2951)  muchos usuarios utilizan la etiqueta junto a mercadopago o wordpress.

Comment: @iuninefrendor agregá una respuesta a esta pregunta con el contexto, la sugerencia de expresión regular y texto de ayuda. Si no estás seguro de qué usar en algún caso, dejalo "a definir" como para que lo vayamos construyendo entre todos.

Comment: @g3rv4 tengo algunas dudas sobre el texto de ayuda, tomaré tu consejo.

Comment: Iba a editar y me quede en el camino para no hacer lio y que sea votado. Agregaria Las preguntas sobre la API de mercado pago tampoco son permitidas. Ver (link a porque no somos.. etc..) bah, si se puede poner un link...

Comment: @gbianchi dale con fe, editá tranquilo (para eso la hice wiki). se puede poner links.

Comment: ¿No les parece cambiar por `mercado.?(?:pago|libre)` y matar dos pájaros de un tiro?

Comment: adelante! TIL `(?:algo|otracosa)` anda

Comment: Cuántos votos más para implementar este? es de las etiquetas más conflictivas

Comment: @lois6b agregado!

Answer (score 12):

## Etiquetas [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) y [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)

Tras la pregunta [¿Que tal si re-etiquetamos Angular y AngularJS?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2934/15855) me he estado fijando en publicaciones con estas etiquetas y veo que a veces ponen ambas (lo cual no creo que sea válido salvo ciertas preguntas) o que ponen la una en vez de la otra.

---

**Expresión regular**: `^angular(js)?[-.\d]*$`

**Aplicar a**: Etiquetas.

**Texto de ayuda**:

> Las etiquetas `angular` y `angularjs` pueden crear confusión.
>
> Por favor, revisa que la usada corresponde con la que tu pregunta necesita.
>
> Para preguntas sobre Angular 2+, usa la etiqueta `angular`; para AngularJS 1.x, usa la etiqueta `angularjs`.

Comment: Texto de ayuda orientativo. Editad si lo creéis conveniente.

Answer (score 7):

## Etiquetas [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error), [errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/errores) y cía.

Creo que lo más importante en este caso es tratar de enseñarle al usuario sobre cómo etiquetar. Originalmente lo había publicado en [La etiqueta [error] se ha quemado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1738/127). Lo muevo acá para que quede ordenada junto al resto.

---

**Expresión regular**: `^er+or[es]*$`

**Aplicar a**: Etiquetas.

**Texto de ayuda**:

> La etiqueta `error` no está permitida.
>
> No intentes resumir la pregunta con etiquetas que no describen el problema.
>   Utiliza etiquetas específicas de la tecnología en la que 
>   este error ocurre (ejemplo: `java` o `c#`).
>   Una etiqueta debería clasificar a la pregunta y definir
>   el alcance esperado en las respuestas.
>   Más información en [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](/help/tagging).

Markdown:

```
La etiqueta `error` no está permitida.

No intentes resumir la pregunta con etiquetas que no describen el problema. Utiliza etiquetas específicas de la tecnología en la que  este error ocurre (ejemplo: `java` o `c#`). Una etiqueta debería clasificar a la pregunta y definir el alcance esperado en las respuestas.  
Más información en [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](/help/tagging).
```

Comment: En este caso no sería una advertencia, sino que estaría prohibido, no?

Comment: @g3rv4 exacto. Sólo lo moví de la publicación de quemado hacia acá porque me pareció que quedaba mejor juntar a todo en el mismo hilo, pero si pensás que no, ningún problema, vuelve a donde estaba.

Comment: Según entiendo en las etiquetas prohibidas no hace falta una expresión regular sin embargo, me parece que sería bueno tener una advertencia para las preguntas que incluyan la palabra error indicando que se debe incluir el error textual y un [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén creo que esa sería una propuesta diferente a la que estoy haciendo... Si crees que es necesaria, adelante (pero ojo con los falsos positivos).

Answer (score 5):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Hace cosa de un año, gbianchi publicó [Recomendar agregar un create de ejemplo en las preguntas de base de datos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2589/83) y en [mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2654/83) precisamente sugerí utilizar estos *warnings*. Entre todos fuimos puliendo el mensaje hasta dejarlo en el que sugiero a continuación.

## SQL

**Expresión regular**: `^sql$`

**Aplicar a**: etiqueta

**Texto de ayuda**:

> Las preguntas de SQL reciben mejores respuestas si...
>   - Incluyen una etiqueta de gestor de bases de datos específico (MySQL, Oracle...)
>   - Muestran el SQL que no funciona.
>   - Describen exactamente en qué no funcionan (mensaje de error, resultados no esperados...)
>   - Describen cuáles son los resultados esperados.
>   - Explican porque se tiene ese modelo de datos (en los casos de modelos no normalizados).
>   - Incluyen el modelo de datos.
>   - Adicionalmente, un [Fiddle de ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/83) resulta muy útil para reproducir el error y poder *jugar* con los datos. Si no, un create de las tablas para poder generarlas.

Comment: Este lo hice directo porque había consenso en la respuesta linkeada.

Answer (score 5):

## Ayuda

**Discusiones relacionadas**:

- [Escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/65)
- [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/65)

**Expresión regular** `/ayuda/i`

**Aplicar a**: Título

**Texto de ayuda:**

> Usualmente los títulos que incluyen "ayuda" son demasiado generales.
>   En este sitio es recomendable que estos sean breves pero específicos e
>   interesantes. Para ideas sobre cómo redactar el título de una pregunta
>   consulta [¿Cómo elaboro una buena
>   pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

## Subida de código fuente como imágenes

**Regex**: `https://i\.stack\.imgur\.com/.+(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)`

Ejemplo a capturar: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bmw7.gif`

**Aplicar a**: cuerpo de la pregunta.

**Texto de ayuda**:

> *Las imágenes pueden ser muy útiles para explicar un problema, pero por favor evita usarlas para mostrar el código fuente. El texto es fácilmente formateable (botón {}) y más legible.*

Comment: ¿Pero cómo sabemos que es código lo que suben? Sugiero poner texto más genérico "... si estás subiendo código..."

Comment: @fedorqui eso intenté yo añadiendo el "recuerda"  hehehe.

Comment: @fedorqui Tienes razón en que habría que buscar una sugerencia más genérica y menos agresiva. Cuando escribí la propuesta no se me ocurrió un texto mejor, pero invito a cualquiera a editar

Comment: Pues me gusta el redactado que habéis dejado entre @lois6b y Pablo, buen trabajo!

Comment: @fedorqui me comenta gerva que está de viaje pero que en breves se pone al dia con las respuestas con más votos de esta publicación :D

Answer (score 5):

## Python

**Expresión regular:** `python`

**Aplicar a:** etiquetas

**Texto de ayuda:**

> Usa la etiqueta [python] para todas las preguntas que hagas sobre Python. Si crees que tu pregunta es específica de alguna versión concreta, añade a la etiqueta anterior otra etiqueta más específica, como [python-2.x] o [python-3.x]. Si utilizas algún paquete como [flask], [django], [numpy], [pandas], [matplotlib] o parecidos, también indícalo.

De acuerdo con lo comentado en [Añadamos [python] a todas las preguntas de Python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/83).

Comment: Planteado por separado en [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83).

Answer (score 4):

Otra frase que se deberia bloquear en los títulos son los saludos, como por ejemplo:

- *hola*
- *como estan*
- *buenas dias, tardes, noche*

**Expresión regular:** `/hola|c[oó]mo est[aá]n|buen([oa]s?)/`

**Aplicar a:** Título

**Texto de ayuda:** (a definir)

Comment: @gbianchi Por ello señalo en mi post:  *Otra frase que se deberia bloquear en **los títulos** son los saludos*

Answer (score 3):

Tomando en cuenta esta otra publicación [¿Por qué se deniega soporte a Woocommerce?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2949/por-qu%C3%A9-se-deniega-soporte-a-woocommerce/2951).

## Woocommerce

**Expresión regular:** `woocommerce`

**Aplicar a:** Todos (Título, cuerpo de la pregunta, etiquetas)

**Texto de ayuda:** (a definir)