# Evitar preguntas escritas solo en mayúsculas

Tags: característica-nueva, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas

Veo que algunos usuarios, por lo regular los usuarios nuevos formulan las preguntas poniendo el título completamente en mayusculas tratando de resaltarla entre las demás.

No sé si sea realmente un problema, pero creo que contribuye a la creación de preguntas mal redactadas ya que se utiliza como recurso para llamar la atención sobre las demás preguntas en lugar de enfocarse en elegir un titulo adecuado al problema.

¿Será posible restringir este tipo de comportamiento con una expresión regular?

Comment: Lo hacen para llamar la atención o simplemente es un descuido, en cualquier caso es inapropiado por lo que estoy acuerdo en que se eviten. ¿La pregunta que incluyes al final es una pregunta retórica? De lo contrario más que una "característica-nueva" sería una "discusión".

Comment: Relacionado [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/65)