# Añadamos [python] a todas las preguntas de Python

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, preguntas

Observo con cierta sorpresa que muchas de las preguntas que se hacen sobre el lenguaje de programación Python contienen solamente una etiqueta especifica sobre una versión.

A saber, [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) es la que se usa comúnmente, pues se refiere a la última *major release* del lenguaje. También se usa con frecuencia [python-2.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), que fue la última *minor release* antes del salto a Python 3.

Creo que sería bueno que sí se usara [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) siempre, pues:

- Ayuda a buscar y encontrar preguntas,
- Ayuda a que haya usuarios con suficiente reputación en la etiqueta como para empezar a usar la medalla de oro para cerrar las preguntas duplicadas unilateralmente.
- Nos prepara mejor para un hipotético futuro con Python 4, donde no resultaría demasiado lógico tener asociadas muchas preguntas con una versión anterior.

Por ejemplo, a día 26 de noviembre de 2018 tenemos:

- 3711 preguntas con [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- 1602 preguntas con [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)
- 499 preguntas con [python-2.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)

Y además:

- 871 preguntas con [`[Python]` y `[Python-3.x]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+python).
- 731 preguntas con [`[Python-3.x]` pero sin `[Python]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+-python), esto es, casi tantas como en el grupo de arriba.
- 316 preguntas con [`[Python]` y `[Python-2.7]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7+python).
- 183 preguntas con [`[Python-2.7]` pero sin `[Python]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7+-python), esto es, algo mejor.

Por tanto, sugiero que se use tal y como el extracto de las etiquetas ya indica actualmente:

- [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) siempre que estemos hablando del lenguaje de programación Python.

  - además, [python-xx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-xx) cuando se trate de un problema asociado con una versión específica del lenguaje.
  - etiquetas propias del tema, tipo [diccionarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diccionarios), [pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), [numpy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy), [listas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listas), [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django)...

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Yo ya estoy en ello. Sería interesante que ayudaran los que tienen >10k, ya que podemos editar las etiquetas sin tener que editar el post completo.

Comment: Yo también estoy de acuerdo. ¿Puede automatizarse o se trata de una petición a que lo hagamos entre todos?

Comment: @abulafia de automatizarse, solo podría un developer. Tendremos que unir fuerzas

Comment: @abulafia bueno mi idea era ver primero qué opinaba la gente aquí en Meta y luego comentároslo a los gurús de la etiqueta para ver si lo empezábamos a hacer desde ya. Finalmente, ir reetiquetando poco a poco. Pero bueno, veo que ha cogido carrerilla el tema y va a ser muy rápido, jeje. Automatizarse no se puede. Lo que sugiero es ir haciendo y aprovechar para mejorar las preguntas, títulos o bien votar para cerrar las que no tengan el nivel.

Comment: Yo de momento solo me estoy centrando en las etiquetas, ya que tampoco soy experto en python como para votar el cierre de preguntas (a no ser que sean muy obvias)..

Comment: Me parece buena iniciativa, en la medida que pueda iré editando preguntas

Comment: Bueno, ya terminé con la etiqueta python3.x (creo). He dejado las preguntas que están cerradas, ya que me molesta que entren en la cola de reapertura, asi que no se que hacer con ellas. Otro día sigo con la etiqueta python2.x, ya que al hacer esto "saturo" la página de preguntas activas con todas las que estoy editando :)

Comment: ¿Tiene sentido que lo edite alguien que está por debajo de 10k? ¿Es ético que lo haga, teniendo en cuenta la reputación que conllevarían esas ediciones?

Comment: ¿Es posible hacerlo de forma más "sutil"? Esta mañana he entrado y, al cabo de un rato, había más de 170 preguntas que habían sido editadas para añadir la etiqueta. Esto ha supuesto que las preguntas que se han hecho por el medio o poco antes se han perdido en la marea. Se pueden encontrar haciendo scroll y demás pero creo que, de normal, un usuario no baja tanto como para llegar a ellas...

Comment: @Rabegi no hay manera más *sutil* de hacerlo.. :/

Comment: @Rabegi no, lamentablemente no se puede hacer de otra manera. De todas maneras, si vas a la pestaña "Recientes" en lugar de a la de "Activas", puedes ver todas las preguntas nuevas (para ello, debes buscar las etiquetas que te interese, por defecto no aparece, algo que no entiendo)

Comment: @meegle84 no es necesario tener 10k para editar directamente, con 2k se puede hacer. 10k lo que permite es editar las etiquetas sin entrar en el modo edición. Por mi no hay probema si quieres editar y llevarte algunos puntos por eso, no sé que opinarán los demás sobre eso

Comment: @blonfu si a alguien mas le parece bien, me pongo a ello. Hace unas horas cuando me he puesto a ello, se lo he comentado a `lois6b`, y me ha sugerido que lo preguntara aquí antes de continuar. Me he llevado unos cuantos puntos de mientras, no tengo ningún problema en perderlos si la situación no ha sido muy ética

Comment: Opino igual q @meegle84, me voy a poner a editar las preguntas, pero no tengo ningún problema si deciden sacarme esos puntos de rep por esa ediciones .

Comment: @meegle yo opino que hacer esto es fantástico, pero lo importante no es hacerlo rápido sino bien: ya que editas, corrige faltas, elimina partes innecesarias, añade o quita etiquetas según convenga, pon títulos más esclarecedores.

Comment: entendido @fedorqui una edición en toda regla, **no solo** para añadir la etiqueta en cuestión. añado que mis ediciones anteriores han sido únicamente por la etiqueta

Comment: @meegle84 yo lo veo así, más que nada porque al no tener aún 2K tu revisión tiene que pasar por el filtro de al menos dos revisores, por lo que involucrar a tres personas (a ti y a esos dos) para una sola etiqueta me parece un gasto excesivo de recursos :) Pero es mi opinión, a ver qué opina el resto

Comment: El problema es cuando ya estamos llenos de etuiquetas como en este caso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7+-python

Comment: @ManucoBianco igual que dije a meegle84, sugiero que complementes la edición con la corrección de otros elementos que sean necesarios. Ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/9155/revisions

Comment: acabo de ver una edicion que dice *"La etiqueta python no debe usarse con la etiqueta python-3.x"*: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/127816

Comment: @lois6b qué bueno que lo vieras. Acabo de consultarle al autor en una pregunta suya, a ver qué comenta.

Comment: A mi, personalmente, me ha resultado muy molesto encontrarme un montón de preguntas editadas en tan poco tiempo. Lo cual ha hecho bajar posiciones a preguntas nuevas, las cuales posiblemente habrán quedado sin respuesta.

Comment: @fly yo lo dudo. Por un lado, la gente suele tener filtros o búsquedas con las etiquetas que sigue. Por otro, yo siempre recomiendo tener activa la pestaña de "Recientes" en lugar de la de "Activas", para evitar este y otros problemas.

Comment: @fedorqui yo rechacé su edicion con un enlace a este post

Comment: ok, gracias @Pikoh lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: @Fly tienes razón en que ha sido molesto, pero lamentablemente no hay otra forma de hacerlo :)

Comment: un apunte ¿las preguntas nuevas de [tag:python-3.x] y [tag:python-2.x] no se les puede añadir el tag [tag:python]?

Comment: @meegle84 no entiendo la pregunta. Todas las preguntas de Python deben usar la etiqueta [tag:python]. Si además tratan sobre algo específico de una versión, añadimos la etiqueta correspondiente.

Comment: quien hace la pregunta es quien pone las etiquetas, si la pregunta especifica una versión de python en las etiquetas, estaría bien que automáticamente se ponga la de [tag:python]

Comment: @meegle84 técnicamente creo que no es posible a día de hoy. La cosa sería sugerirlo aquí en Meta y ver si se puede conseguir. Lo que sí voy a proponer es algún tipo de mensaje en [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83)