# ¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta [python*]?

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas, advertencias-en-preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

Para relanzar el tema y desbloquear votos, pues el [CM Nicolas comenta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49042955#49042955) una cosa razonable, el planteamiento de mi propuesta es el siguiente:

**Propongo que siempre que alguien use la etiqueta `python` + `algún carácter` (esto es [pythonx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonx), le aparecerá un mensaje del tipo:**

> Usa la etiqueta [python] para todas las preguntas que hagas sobre Python. Si crees que tu pregunta es específica de alguna versión concreta, añade a la etiqueta anterior otra etiqueta más específica, como [python-2.x] o [python-3.x]. Si utilizas algún paquete como [flask], [django], [numpy], [pandas], [matplotlib] o parecidos, también indícalo con su correspondiente etiqueta.

**¿Creéis que es útil y válido? ¿Se os ocurre alguna representación menos intrusiva?**

Por favor, comentad y votar positiva o negativamente para que los CM puedan determinar si la comunidad desea esta advertencia o no:

---

Hace unas semanas planteé [Añadamos [python] a todas las preguntas de Python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/83). A tenor de los comentarios recibidos y los votos (+14/-0 a 11 de enero, unos 50 días después de publicada), parece que hubo consenso en que sería bueno que todas las preguntas de Python tengan como mínimo la etiqueta [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) y, adicionalmente, puedan tener otras específicas tanto de versión de Python (si es necesario) como del framework o lo que sea.

Movido por ese consenso [planteé](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3791/83) en la pregunta [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83) que se añadiera una advertencia en las preguntas, de modo que cuando alguien etiquetara con `python*` le saliera un aviso informando:

> ## Python
>
> **Expresión regular:** `python`
>
> **Aplicar a:** etiquetas
>
> **Texto de ayuda:**
>
> > Usa la etiqueta [python] para todas las preguntas que hagas sobre Python. Si crees que tu pregunta es específica de alguna versión
> >     concreta, añade a la etiqueta anterior otra etiqueta más específica,
> >     como [python-2.x] o [python-3.x]. Si utilizas algún paquete como
> >     [flask], [django], [numpy], [pandas], [matplotlib] o parecidos,
> >     también indícalo.
>
> De acuerdo con lo comentado en
>   [Añadamos [python] a todas las preguntas de Python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/83).

Rápidamente se obtuvo una puntuación de 6 (+6/-0) que le daría suficiente empaque para implementarla. Sin embargo, en esas fechas hubo cierto debate sobre la forma de proceder para estas peticiones (véanse los comentarios a la pregunta) y se dejaron de implementar.

Por ello, dos cosas:

- ¿Podemos retomar la inclusión de advertencias problemáticas?
- En particular, ¿podemos añadir esta advertencia para las preguntas que tengan alguna etiqueta `python*`? Lo digo porque [`[Python-3.x]` pero sin `[Python]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+-python) crece día a día y me parece una pérdida de tiempo actuar sobre la consecuencia sin ir a la causa.

Comment: yo creo solamente toca esperar a que esté terminado el asistente: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype

Comment: @RuslanLópez uy las cosas de palacio van despacio. Ojalá llegue el asistente pronto, pero aún faltan meses seguramente. Las advertencias en preguntas vienen funcionando desde hace tiempo, son relativamente rápidas de añadir y creo que son bastante útiles. Veamos...

Comment: Me parece bien, pero es cierto que si el usuario ya usó la etiqueta `[python]` el mensaje no debería aparecerle. ¿Funcionaría con la expresión regular `python.+`? Esto obliga a que haya más caracteres tras python por lo que encajaría con `python-3.x`, `python-2.7`, `python-2.x`, `python-requests`, `python-3.7` y `python-docx`, pero no con `python` a secas. ¿Debería aparecer también la advertencia ante preguntas etiquetadas `numpy`, `matplotlib`, `flask`, etc?

Comment: @abulafia el sistema actualmente no permite cosas complejas como comparar qué otras etiquetas se usan ([fuente](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48697192#48697192)). Por tanto, lo que sugieres de `python.+` parece una muy buena idea para evitar que salte el mensaje cuando ya se está poniendo correctamente `[python]`. Actualizo la propuesta con tu sugerencia, ¡gracias!

Comment: Mis disculpas por no seguir el tema desde el principio. Después de tanta polémica, considero que fue un error añadir número de versiones en las etiquetas. Tenía que haber sido [tag:python] para todo y sugerir indicar las versiones como parte del contenido.

Para *reeducar* al usuario, el texto debería ser más conciso y ajustado a la conducta que se quiera corregir. Poco caso hará el usuario de consejos generales si ya ha decidido la etiqueta que va a usar. Sería más apropiado advertir que python2 va a quedar fuera de mantenimiento o que es mejor poner [tag:python] que sólo [tag:python-3.x].

Comment: @ChemaCortes gracias por pasarte por aquí! La verdad es que creo que es útil tener etiquetas específicas, pues permite hacer búsquedas más completas y filtrar mejor. Por ello, creo que es un buen complemento a explicar las versiones en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: @fedorqui Una etiqueta determina el problema, pero delimita su solución. Por un lado tienes mejor definido el contexto del problema; por otro lado, tienes más limitaciones para dar soluciones. Por ejemplo: si un usuario describe un problema con un módulo cuando trabaja con django, la solución tiene que funcionar para django, aunque django no sea culpable directo del problema. A veces me pregunto, ¿se puede responder una pregunta etiquetada como python2 con una solución en python3? Al usuario no le servirá, pero al resto de visitantes, presentes y futuros, puede que sea justo lo que buscaban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nicolas comenta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49635699#49635699) que esto ya está activo:

Efectivamente, ahora si al formular una pregunta uno añade una etiqueta cuyo nombre coincide con `python.*`, le aparece el mensaje:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como el sistema no tiene actualmente capacidad de *ver* las otras etiquetas que tiene la pregunta, este mensaje también aparece si ya se ha puesto [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Está en nuestras manos decidir si nos gusta esta manera: si el relativo engorro de ver el mensaje en algunos casos en que no hace falta compensa la cantidad de veces que sí es útil y necesario. Por lo pronto, esperemos que disminuya la cantidad de preguntas sobre Python sin la etiqueta [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (con [`[Python-3.x]` pero sin `[Python]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+-python) o con [`[Python]` pero sin `[Python-2.7]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7+-python)).

¡Es tarea de todos mantener el sitio ordenado! Cuanto mejor ordenado, más fácil será encontrar cosas.