# ¿Deberían todas las preguntas con etiqueta [phpmyadmin] llevar la etiqueta [mysql]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

La pregunta está en el título.

¿Todas las preguntas con etiqueta [phpmyadmin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) deberían llevar la etiqueta [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)?

Si es sí, ¿por qué sí? Y, ¿se podría emprender alguna acción en ese sentido?

Si es no, ¿por qué no?

### Algunos datos estadísticos

- [Consulta para ver las preguntas que tienen dos etiquetas (en este caso `phpmyadmin` y `mysql`)](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/975844/posts-que-tienen-dos-etiquetas-dadas-escribir-nombres-de-etiquetas-en-minuscula). Esta consulta sirve para ver dos etiquetas cualesquiera.
- [Consulta para ver las preguntas que tienen `phpmyadmin` y no tienen `mysql` o viceversa](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/975867/posts-que-tienen-una-etiqueta-dada-y-no-tienen-otra-etiqueta-dada-escribir-etiqu) Esta consulta sirve para comparar entre dos etiquetas cualesquiera de forma dinámica.

Comment: en realidad, salvo que tengas un problema particular con phpmyadmin (no con la base de datos), casi ninguna pregunta directamente deberia llevar la etiqueta phpmyadmin...

Comment: A. Cedano: ya que eres de los más expertos en el tema, ¿a ti qué te parece? Para tener elementos de análisis.

Comment: Sobre acciones a emprender, sí se puede. Véase [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83) y la que sugerí yo de [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83)

Comment: Mi sugerencia sería al revés: Hay muchas preguntas con la etiqueta `phpmyadmin` que no tienen nada que ver con dicha herramienta, al parecer la gran mayoría de personas lo confunden con `mysql`. Eventualmente hago alguna que otra minijornada de limpieza de etiquetas phpmyadmin donde no son necesarias.

Comment: Yo estoy con @shaz. Creo que el enfoque es sustituir la etiqueta [tag:phpmyadmin] por [tag:mysql] en una gran mayoría de preguntas. Opino igual que él que hay una confusión muy común entre la herramienta y el sistema de base de datos. El problema es que habría que analizar una por una las preguntas para ir modificando los tags...

Comment: También sería bueno empezar cambiando el extracto por algo parecido a [lo que hay en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/phpmyadmin/info): _Usa esta etiqueta para plantear problemas con esta herramienta, no para consultas de queries_.

Comment: @Shaz he añadido a la pregunta dos consultas que arrojan datos interesantes y que quizá confirman lo que dices. En la segunda consulta por ejemplo, si busco las preguntas con etiqueta `phpmyadmin` y sin `mysql` se puede ver que hay hasta preguntas que tienen la etiqueta `mysqli` o `PDO` y nada de `mysql`...

Comment: Nótese que estas consultas se pueden hacer con operadores directamente. Es mejor porque SEDE solo se actualiza semanalmente. Simplemente usa [`[mysql] [phpmyadmin]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin+mysql) y [`-[mysql] [phpmyadmin]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin+-mysql).

Comment: @fedorqui no lo tenía tan claro, precisamente por eso lancé la pregunta aquí en meta. Y ahora que hice unas consultas comparativas no sigue siendo tan claro, lo que sí queda claro, viendo resultados sobre todo de la segunda consulta, es que `phpmyadmin` puede ser una etiqueta problemática dado que mucha gente lo confunde con `mysql`  es sí. Va a ser interesante usar las consultas que acabo de poner en la pregunta para ver por ejemplo preguntas con `phpmyadmin` y `pdo` o `mysqli` ... o crear una query en la que se busquen preguntas con `phpmyadmin`, otra etiqueta dada y sin `mysql`...

Comment: @fedorqui gracias por el dato. Acabo de hacer una prueba con esto: `[phpmyadmin] [pdo] -[mysql]` y arroja resultados interesantes: un solo usuario ha escrito preguntas con ese caso. Creo que en situaciones como esas se puede regularizar la situación poniendo comentario al usuario en una de sus preguntas para que aprenda a distinguir entre `phpmyadmin` y `mysql`.

Comment: A. Cedano: sobre tu último comentario, veo que el usuario ya hace tiempo que no entra en el sitio. Probablemente se podría empezar con lo de cambiar el extracto y quitar la etiqueta [tag:phpmyadmin] en estos subconjuntos de preguntas. Y, claro está, aprovechar las ediciones para cambiar otras cosas que se puedan mejorar en las preguntas.

Comment: Ya hice el cambio en el extracto de la etiqueta y reetiqueté todas las [`[phpmyadmin] [pdo] -[mysql]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin+pdo+-mysql).

Comment: A. Cedano: ¿en qué quedó todo esto? Era una buena iniciativa que estaría bien llevar a término.