# ¿Se pueden crear diferentes etiquetas según la versión?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, etiquetas

**Por ejemplo :** Normalmente cuando hacen una pregunta sobre ***MySQL, PHP, etc.*** Simplemente pone [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) y luego los usuarios le pregunta qué versión es. Y yo os pregunto: ¿no sería más fácil crear etiquetas como [mysql-8.1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-8.1), [mysql-5.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-5.7) o con ***PHP*** igual: [php7.1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php7.1), [php7.4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php7.4), etc.

En stack Overflow en inglés ya contemplan estas etiquetas.

### Stack Overflow en inglés

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Stack Overflow en español

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algunas de esas etiquetas ya existen. No? No todas, pero algunas ya están. No veo conveniente usar el versionado semántico. Basta con `mysql5` y no `mysql5.1`, pero es mi opinón solamente.

Comment: Pues si pero no con la version completa por ejemplo en php hay una que es php7 pero 7 que mas  1 , 2 , 3.... yo por ejemplo cree la etiqueta ``mysql8``

Comment: Claro, es recomendable. Siempre la principal y luego añades las de la versión, si es algo relevante para la pregunta (porque la funcionalidad varía según versiones). Preguntas relacionadas pero en el otro sentido: [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83)