# ¿Qué sentido tiene el hecho de tener varias etiquetas de Ionic?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

¿Por qué tenemos las etiquetas [ionic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic) y [ionic-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework)?

Para empezar creo que estas podrían ir en una misma etiqueta fusionadas, esto lo digo porque la mayor parte de las preguntas que he visto con estas etiquetas son preguntas relacionadas con el framework en general sin importar la versión del mismo por lo cual la etiqueta debería de quedar solamente como [ionic-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework).

Ademas de esto tenemos las etiquetas de [ionic2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2), [ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic3) y [ionic4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic4) de las cuales al menos [ionic2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2) y [ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic3) deberían ir en una misma etiqueta llamada [ionic-2-3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-2-3) debido a que entre estas dos versiones no hay cambios tan drásticos como para dividir la etiqueta, a diferencia de lo que seria la etiqueta [ionic4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic4) que sí apunta a una versión con cambios muy grandes respecto a las otras y que requiere de su propia etiqueta.

Comment: Si [tag:ionic] y [tag:ionic-framework] son técnicamente lo mismo, lo procedente sería fusionarlas. En [so] lo están.

Comment: En cuanto a las versiones: ¿ves plausible una pregunta que sea compatible con Ionic2 pero no con Ionic3? La clave de las etiquetas por versiones es poder preguntar por una versión específica, tanto como sea necesario. Tú eres el experto en esta tecnología, ¿ves motivo para ello? En SO veo que todas estas etiquetas son independientes, cada una con sus millares de preguntas.

Comment: Por ejemplo hay [20 preguntas con ionic2 e ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2+ionic3) y [97 preguntas con ioni2 y no ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2+-ionic3)

Comment: @fedorqui Hola de nuevo, pues mira respondiendo a la pregunta de si veo motivo para que estas 2 etiquetas existan por aparte pues esta es mi respuesta y espero no sonar arrogante. La cuestión es que al menos con esa tecnología la razón del cambio de versión entre 2 y 3 fue solo motivo de publicidad mas que de cambios y fue tan mínimo el cambio que fue motivo de broma en esta comunidad, anexo un link para que veas a lo que me refiero: http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2017/04/ionic-3.html

Comment: @fedorqui Nuevamente espero no haber sonado descortés, arrogante, prepotente o algo parecido, esto lo menciono por la razón de que un texto no se le puede dar muchas veces el todo que se le daría en una conversación cara a cara por lo que se podría mal interpretar en ocasiones.

Comment: @ASASCED No siendo experto en el tema pienso que tener las etiquetas por versiones ayuda a diferenciar, por algo se hizo el cambio de versión en ionic (No tomo en cuenta los blogs no oficiales como el que señalas pues son opiniones pero no es nada oficial), en cambio eliminarlos no aporta nada ya que quizas una solución funciona en ionic3 pero no en ionic2, o viceversa.

Comment: Seria genial que algun experto en esa etiqueta de su opinión al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic/topusers, https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic/topusers, etc

Comment: @eyllanesc buena idea. He dejado un comentario a tres de los usuarios más importantes de esta etiqueta, animándoles a echar una ojeada a este debate.

Comment: ASASCED: para nada :) Las opiniones de los expertos son lo fundamental. Veo en SO alguna pregunta en la que se destacan problemas al cambiar de versión ([ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45452385/1983854)). El mero hecho de que exista hace pensar que una pregunta etiquetada con [tag:ionic2] o [tag:ionic3] puede tener relevancia. Recordemos que al fin y al cabo las etiquetas están para compartimentar y facilitar la búsqueda: no molestan, sino que ayudan. A poco que haya un matiz, creo mejor mantener la diferenciación de etiquetas. A ver qué comentan los expertos.

Comment: @ASASCED Como señala fedorqui las etiquetas tienen como funciones: 1) Facilitar la búsqueda, 2) atraer atención de una comunidad específica 3)Ayudar a los que intentan responder ya que da nociones de las limitaciones(por ejemplo a veces piden hacer un *backport*, indicar que se desea usar ciertas funcionalidades de acuerdo a la versión). Al menos esas son las que conozco. Y su uso debe ser meditado, por ejemplo yo usaria la etiqueta principal ionic para todas las preguntas y si quiero señalar que necesito la funcionalidad para cierta version usaria tambien las etiquetas versionadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Por qué tenemos las etiquetas [ionic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic) y [ionic-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework)? (...) la mayor parte de las preguntas que he visto con estas etiquetas son preguntas relacionadas con el framework en general sin importar la versión del mismo por lo cual la etiqueta debería de quedar solamente como [ionic-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework).

Estoy de acuerdo. Por lo que veo, Ionic en sí es un framework, por lo que sería equivalente a tener [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) y [django-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-framework) (pongo un ejemplo de lo que conozco). Por tanto, unamos estas etiquetas (sinónimo + merge) y pongamos la que nos dé más rabia como principal. En SO se comentó hace unos cuantos años y se obró igual: [Tags: [ionic] or [ionic-framework] — 2 tags with same meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285228/1983854). Ellos usan [ionic-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework) como principal.

> Ademas de esto tenemos las etiquetas de [ionic2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2), [ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic3) y [ionic4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic4) de las cuales al menos [ionic2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2) y [ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic3) deberían ir en una misma etiqueta llamada [ionic-2-3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-2-3) debido a que entre estas dos versiones no hay cambios tan drásticos como para dividir la etiqueta, a diferencia de lo que seria la etiqueta [ionic4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic4) que sí apunta a una versión con cambios muy grandes respecto a las otras y que requiere de su propia etiqueta.

A poco que haya diferencias, las etiquetas específicas de versión deberían mantenerse. No es solo lo que hay a día de hoy, sino cómo queremos que la taxonomía crezca de forma ordenada: ¿hay opciones de que alguien venga con una pregunta sobre por qué la migración a Ionic 3 le dio problemas? En tal caso, es necesaria la etiqueta [ionic3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic3) diferenciada de [ionic2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2).

Veo que en Stack Overflow diferencian estas etiquetas, por lo que estoy inclinado por sugerir que se mantengan diferenciadas.

---

Además, creo importante recordar que *siempre* deberíamos usar la tecnología principal cuando formulemos preguntas de cualquier tema. En este caso, no debería haber preguntas con [ionic2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2) pero sin [ionic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic). Sin embargo, está pasando ([57 resultados de etiquetadas con [tag:ionic2] pero no [tag:ionic] ni [tag:ionic-framework]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2+-ionic+-ionic-framework), por ejemplo).

Lo comenté para Python en [Añadamos [python] a todas las preguntas de Python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/83) y creo que aplica también a todos, por lo que iniciativas como [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta [python*]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83) creo que debían extenderse.

Comment: Estoy totaente de acuerdo con lo que dices y creo que en cuanto a el tema de que las personas usan la etiqueta ionic 2 o 3 y no usan la etiqueta ionic para complementar por decirlo de alguna manera seria nuestro trabajo como comunidad de editar ese tipo de preguntas para acostumbrar a aquellos que usan esas esas etiquetas para que las usen correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Es cierto que desde Ionic 2 a Ionic 3 no hubieron cambios relevantes pero Ionic Team ha juntado ambas versiones y en algunos artículos nombran que Ionic 3 fue una versión de "espera" (para dejarnos tranquilos jejeje) para la nueva versión de Ionic 4. Pueden revisar el [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) y verificar que Ionic 2 y 3 es básicamente lo mismo. A mi parecer, deberían haber etiquetas: [ionic-v1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-v1), [ionic-v2-v3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-v2-v3) y [ionic-v4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-v4) ***ya que el paso de Ionic 1 a cualquier otra versión o Ionic 2-3 a Ionic 4 es un cambio bastante drástico y de seguro va a haber bastante pregunta-respuesta.***

¿Por qué la etiqueta quitar [ionic-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework)?

Es cierto que Ionic es un Framework, pero las diferencias entre versiones son bastantes y hasta que no haya una versión "estable" del framework como tal no me parece una etiqueta principal para unificar las preguntas.

Definición de la etiqueta [ionic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic)  [en el foro principal de Ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/about-the-ionic-category/136377):

> The Ionic category is for all posts related to the `@ionic/core` or
>   `@ionic/angular` package of the framework itself.
>
> If you have any questions about the forum, please use the meta tag
>   instead.
>
> Use the Ionic-v1 category for posts related to version 1 of Ionic
>   Framework
>
> Use the Ionic-v3 category for posts related to version 2-3 of Ionic
>   Framework

Comment: No entiendo la segunda parte: ¿defiendes tener [tag:ionic] y [tag:ionic-framework] por separado? ¿O qué etiqueta sugieres para englobar todo lo relacionado con Ionic?

Comment: No me parece tener ninguna de las dos, tampoco englobar Ionic como framework por la sencilla razón que el framework tiene distintas versiones que ninguna tiene que ver con la otra. Y cuando se intenta hacer una pregunta del framework, te aseguro que el 90% de las preguntas son de Angular (o angularJS) y no de Ionic como framework

Comment: edito mi respuesta y dejo la fuente principal de la categoria "Ionic" en el foro

Comment: Sobre ionic2 vs ionic3: que no haya nada especialmente relevante no sé si es condición suficiente para juntar las etiquetas. Veo en SO preguntas incluso con la etiqueta python-3.1, pasando por todas las versiones hasta la 3.5 que es la que todo el mundo usa. Opino que a poco que haya situaciones en que sea útil, mejor usarla.

Comment: Yo tampoco termino de tenerlo claro, pero por lo que saco de lo que decís parece que lo lógico es hacer lo mismo que en SO, es decir, tener una sola etiqueta principal ([tag:ionic] o [tag:ionic-framework]) y mantener, al menos de momento, las etiquetas de versiones. Por coherencia con estas, yo elegiría [tag:ionic], ya que las de versiones son [tag:ionicX] + @fedorqui

Comment: Para mi un cambió pequeño entre 2 versiones no implican que sean la misma versión, segun he leído(corrijanme si estoy equivocado) el cambio que se dío entre ionic2 e ionic3 fue cambiar la base que conllevaba una mejora en el rendimiento, es decir no se modifico la última que ve el desarrollador sino la capa base. Asi que para mí las etiquetas versionadas deben persistir, ya que quitarlos no contribuyen en nada.

Comment: @eyllanesc coincido contigo. En los comentarios a la pregunta indiqué [un ejemplo de pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45325392/1983854) en el que la diferencia entre ionic2 e ionic3 es relevante. Dado que no veo improbable que haya más, creo que tener las etiquetas separadas hace más bien que mal.