# ¿Son válidas las preguntas del tipo "ayuda con este código"?

Tags: discusión

He visto algunas preguntas con títulos del estilo *"Ayuda con este código"*, *"problema en este código"* durante mi tiempo en StackOverflow y entiendo que una pregunta debe de ser de ayuda para cualquier otro que tenga el mismo problema. Por lo que yo considero que un título **debe ser relevante** para que una pregunta tenga calidad. (Aunque probablemente yo también haya pecado de esto alguna vez)

Creo que este tipo de títulos, personalmente, no me parecen apropiados para hacer una pregunta en el sitio, ya que aunque aporten algo relevante, la realidad es que si algún usuario se encuentra con el mismo problema, al no encontrar solución, sería libre de escribir otra pregunta similar, y rizando el rizo, con el mismo título de *"ayuda con este codigo"*.

Permitir este tipo de títulos me parece un ***coladero de respuestas duplicadas***, entonces, me vienen varias preguntas.

> - ¿Deberían de permitirse este tipo de preguntas?

En caso de no permitirse, ¿Deberían de reportarse si el OP no corrige el título? ¿Debería de editarse el título a uno más apropiado?

> - ¿Es más apropiado votar una pregunta negativamente por, lo que yo considero, un título vago?

Esto dejando un comentario al OP diciéndole que busque un título mejor.

> - Ejemplos donde he visto este tipo de títulos.

[duda sobre este codigo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200179/duda-sobre-este-codigo)

[Porque este codigo en angular no funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42132/porque-este-codigo-en-angular-no-funciona)

[porqué este codigo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220381/porqu%C3%A9-este-codigo-funciona)

[me ayudan con este codigo java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138362/me-ayudan-con-este-codigo-java)

Comment: Es un problema que no tiene solucion. Por desgracia, es peor cuando se ayuda con ese codigo, y no se modifica el titulo por lo menos aclarando cual era el problema.

Comment: Lo gracioso es que ya [hay una advertencia para cuando un título dice "ayuda"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3453/83) --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9ZRf.png

Comment: @fedorqui si tuvieramos los datos de las metricas del sitio podriamos ver cuántos hacen caso de esas advertencias ... porque analitics si que está en SOes (aunque solo son pageviews parece ser. con un etiquetado más completo aprenderíamos mucho de los usuarios)

Comment: aún así, nadie me ha respondido, ¿Son válidas o no? ¿Se pueden poner? ¿Está bien, está mal?

Comment: 1. Son válidas. 2. Sí, de lo contrario no estarían (o estarían cerradas). 3. Si está bien formulado el cuerpo de la pregunta, está bien. Sugerencia: Editar el título (aún si la pregunta no es nuestra) para que refleje el verdadero problema por resolver.

Comment: En lo personal, si la pregunta dice de esa forma entraría sin problema alguno, agregando que estaría ideal que mínimo colocaran el lenguaje del cual se trata el código, pero si me gustaría que en la descripción del problema venga todo detallado.