# Escribamos extractos de etiquetas que expliquen cuándo usar la etiqueta, no qué es

Tags: discusión, ediciones, extracto-de-etiquetas

Con cierta frecuencia me encuentro en la cola de revisión de [Ediciones sugeridas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) con sugerencias de creación o mejora de extractos de etiquetas. En muchos casos me veo obligado a seleccionar la opción *Rechazar* con el motivo:

> La mera definición de qué es una [etiqueta] raramente sirve de ayuda para aquellos que la usan, a no ser que el propio nombre de la etiqueta sea ambiguo. El resumen debería describir por qué y cuándo debería usarse esta. [Consulta el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) para más información.

Es una pena porque alguien ha invertido algo de su tiempo en sugerir algo pero que no es lo que realmente sugiere el artículo [¿Qué debería contener el extracto de etiqueta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts).

Repasemos lo que dice para intentar llegar a un consenso y hacer crecer estas piezas de información de forma productiva para todos:

> 1. **El extracto es el texto de presentación de una etiqueta.** Solo tienes ~500 caracteres de texto sin formato para el extracto, ¡así que no te sientas obligado a cubrirlo todo en él! Guárdalo para la wiki de etiqueta, donde puedes utilizar markdown y hasta 30.000 caracteres. El extracto debe definir la naturaleza compartida de las preguntas que contienen esta etiqueta, explicada en unas pocas oraciones cortas.
> 2. **Evita definir conceptos genéricos en una etiqueta**, a menos que sea altamente especializada. La etiqueta "correo electrónico", por ejemplo, *no* necesita explicar qué es un correo electrónico. Podemos asumir con seguridad que la mayoría de los usuarios de Internet saben qué es un correo electrónico; no aporta ningún valor dar una explicación trillada sobre qué es correo electrónico.
> 3. **Concéntrate en lo que significa una etiqueta para *tu* comunidad.** Para "correo electrónico" en [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), menciona los aspectos del servidor de correo electrónico, incluidos POP3, SMTP, IMAP y el software del servidor. Para "correo electrónico" en [Super User](https://superuser.com/), menciona los clientes de correo electrónico de escritorio y excluye explícitamente el correo web, ya que sería más apropiado para el sitio [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).
> 4. **Proporciona una guía básica sobre cuándo usar la etiqueta.** En otras palabras, *¿Qué tipo de preguntas debería tener esta etiqueta?* Las etiquetas solo existen como formas de organizar preguntas, de modo que si no proporcionamos la orientación adecuada sobre qué preguntas *necesitan* esta etiqueta, no se etiquetarán en absoluto, haciendo que el extracto de la etiqueta sea discutible. Piensa en ello como una propuesta: en una sala llena de etiquetas que gritan "¡seleccióname!", ¿qué convencería a quien pregunta para que seleccione tu etiqueta?
> 5. **Algunas etiquetas son de conocimiento común.** La mayoría de las etiquetas requieren un poco de explicación en el extracto, incluso si solo son 3 o 4 palabras. Pero si la etiqueta es de conocimiento común, es decir, si *te acercaras a una persona al azar en la calle y le dijeras el nombre de la etiqueta*, ellos sabrían de qué estaba hablando, entonces no te molestes en explicar la etiqueta en absoluto. Indica en el extracto cuál es el uso que la comunidad le está dando.

Todo esto sale de la entrada de blog [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) que escribió Jeff Atwood en marzo de 2011.

Por tanto, creo que es fundamental que usemos estos pocos caracteres para explicar *cuándo* debe usarse esta etiqueta y no *qué* es el concepto.

Ejemplos serían:

- *Utilízalo conjuntamente con la versión del lenguaje que usas.*
- *Si la pregunta es sobre X, mejor no uses la etiqueta [Z].*

Que vienen a funcionar como [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83).

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. El extracto debe contener como mínimo la indicación de uso de la etiqueta.