# Al sugerir un sinónimo para [postgresql] me dice que la etiqueta está prohibida

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Entré en la página de sinónimos de la etiqueta [postgresql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) para sugerir [postgres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgres) como sinónimo (para facilitar el uso, pues casi todos lo llamamos Postgres y no PostgreSQL).

Sin embargo, al ir a hacerlo me dio un error raro:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, dice:

> No se pudo proponer el sinónimo:
>   La etiqueta postgresql está prohibida

¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿Cómo puede estar prohibida si precisamente existe? El error ocurre al intentar añadir cualquier sinónimo ("bla", etc).

Comment: Sospecho que el problema viene al tener la etiqueta "alertas de uso", pero no consigo confirmarlo ni ver como solucionarlo. Seguiremos investigando, aunque creo que se trata de algun tipo de bug. [Esto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284326/579895) es lo único que he encontrado.

Comment: @Pikoh ¡gracias! Buen hallazgo. Era un bug entonces (2015) y lo marcaron como resuelto.

Comment: hay que sugerir el sinonimo tambien para psql , lo haria yo, pero no tengo 5 puntos para hacerlo

Comment: @JackNavaRow totalmente de acuerdo. Cuando este bug se solucione lo hacemos.

Comment: @JackNavaRow ya sugerí el sinónimo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/synonyms  Probablemente haya que pedir a un moderador que lo apruebe, pues poca gente puede votar y aún menos usuarios entran en la página de sinónimos.

Comment: @Pikoh dado que es imposible que la gente vote los sinónimos y se aprueben antes del fin de mundo, ¿podríais los moderadores aceptar las dos peticiones que hice? (la mía + la de JackNavaRow)

Comment: @fedorqui hecho

Comment: @Pikoh ¡mil gracias!

Comment: @JackNavaRow ^^^

Comment: gracias @fedorqui y a nuestro mod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto pasaba porque teníamos [una advertencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/11272) universal (título + cuerpo + tags) cuya expresión regular era `sql`. Entonces, [postgresql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) no sólo mostraba la advertencia sino que tampoco podía ser destino de un sinónimo (si una etiqueta tiene un advertencia, la creación de sinónimos falla).

Para resolver esto, [Adam Lear](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16/adam-lear) y yo (bah, básicamente Adam... porque yo ya no tengo privilegios \o/) modificó la advertencia de esta forma:

- Aplica a: etiqueta
- Expresión regular: `^sql$`

Al hacer esto, preguntas que tengan sql en el título o en el cuerpo no van a mostrar la advertencia. Nos pareció sensato ya que es bastante común usar sql como palabra en una pregunta aunque sea sobre un motor de base de datos específico.

Si esto parece una mala idea, lo podemos charlar en una pregunta específica.

Comment: ¡Gracias por investigarlo! ¿blacklist = advertencia? Por otra parte, entiendo que das un _workaround_, pero no deja de ser un bug, ¿verdad?

Comment: un blacklist puede ser una advertencia o una etiqueta bloqueada (como [tag:es]), depende de su BlockType. Si hay un blacklist que aplica a la etiqueta de destino (independientemente de su tipo) el sinónimo falla... yo diría que es un bug, pero el código explícitamente hace el chequeo, así que suena a decisión consciente (y a que el error fue mío al crear la advertencia para sql)

Comment: Ajá. Entiendo pues que algo así como `[xxxmercadopagoxxx]` también daría error, pues la advertencia aplica a todo: título, etiquetas y cuerpo.

Comment: No sé cómo se debería proceder, realmente como son cosas que solo un empleado puede hacer, haced lo que consideréis mejor :)

Comment: le hago ping a algún dev que sea mod acá (ya no tengo súper poderes)

Comment: @g3rv4 si te fijas en el el post de meta que puse en mi comentario a la pregunta, parecería que es un bug que se resolvió en stack overflow y no aqui...

Comment: @Pikoh interesante... lo que Samo arregló fue que si una alerta es de tipo Tag, entonces no bloquee la creación del sinónimo... pero en nuestro caso, era de tipo `Universal`.

Comment: Genial! Acabo de confirmar que funciona, ya hice la sugerencia de sinónimo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/synonyms. Muchas gracias g3rv4 y Adam, así como @Pikoh por seguirlo.