# ¿Son redundantes las etiquetas [consulta-sql], [query] y [consulta]?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

Estas tres etiquetas se usan mucho en preguntas del entorno de SQL:

[consulta-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consulta-sql), que tiene 188 preguntas y [se define como](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/consulta-sql/info):

> Sentencia estructurada, según las normas del lenguaje SQL, utilizada para obtener información almacenada en una base de datos SQL.

[query](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query) tiene 622, con [definición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/query/info):

> Cuando se habla de forma genérica, query se tratarse de una inserción, actualización, búsqueda y/o eliminación en una base de datos, vale decir que es un script en lenguaje de base de datos.

y [consulta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consulta) con 155.

Por otro lado, ya tenemos [insert](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/insert), [update](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/update) (y [actualizacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actualizacion), no sinónima).

Además, cuando uno pregunta por algo relacionado con [SQL le sale este mensaje de aviso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que ya de inicio debería tener SQL + gestor.

Por ello, pregunto: ¿qué utilidad tienen [consulta-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consulta-sql) y [query](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query) si el problema se define mejor con las etiquetas principales, junto con -tal vez- [insert](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/insert), [update](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/update) y similares? ¿No son redundantes?

Comment: Respuesta corta: si. Respuesta larga: si, para mi son redundantes. Basta con [tag:sql] y añadiendo en todo caso otra etiqueta.

Comment: Yo suelo etiquetarlas como mencionas `sql + el gestor` me ha parecido mas simple y con mejor futuro para encontrar referencias, pero igual seguiré de cerca la publicación para saber si se debe hacer de otro modo

Comment: "consulta" y "subconsulta" no tienen ninguna descripción asociada, por lo que pueden aplicarse a cualquier cosa (consulta BD, consulta DNS, consulta el tiempo ...). Más que redundantes, inútiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las etiquetas

- [consulta-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consulta-sql)
- [query](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query)
- [consulta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consulta)

son todas sinónimos de [sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) (y fueron reemplazadas por ella). Se puede ver en el [listado de sinónimos de sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/synonyms)

Comment: ¡excelente! muchas gracias