# Problemas en "advertencias en preguntas problemáticas"

Tags: discusión, respuesta, advertencias-en-preguntas

En [Advertencias en preguntas potencialemente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/127) empezamos a usar las advertencias como una excelente herramienta para intentar mejorar la calidad del sitio.

Ya lo aplicamos para:

- [Mercado Pago](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3300/127)
- [SQL](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3301/127), que surgió a partir de:
  [Recomendar agregar un create de ejemplo en las preguntas de base de datos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2589/127).

**Problema**. Encontramos que cuando una regla se aplica al **cuerpo de la publicación**, se aplica tanto a preguntas **como a respuestas**. Eso implica que por ejemplo empecemos a redactar una respuesta que contenga "SQL" y nos aparezca la notificación (cuando el editor pierde el foco). Actualmente no existe una forma de diferenciar entre cuerpo de pregunta y cuerpo de respuesta.

> [image: respuesta con el texto "SQL" en donde aparece la notificación]

Que aparezca en todas las respuestas que incluyan el texto "SQL" es un tanto incómodo.

**Propuesta**. Viendo esto, se me ocurre que lo mejor sería:

1. Dejar la notificación de `Mercado Pago` como está, porque nos trae más problemas que soluciones. Si la comunidad de expertos en esta etiqueta en algún momento se hace cargo de estos problemas, ahí podemos ver de modificarlo.
2. Modificar la regla de `SQL`, que siga aplicando a título y etiquetas, pero no al cuerpo de la publicación.

No se me ocurre nada mejor, quizás alguien tenga otra idea. ¿Qué les parece?

---

**Modificación**. Además, si quisiéramos modificar el funcionamiento de las notificaciones, para que se pueda distinguir entre pregunta y respuesta, debería hacerse en [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com). Yo no lo voy a hacer, quien quiera puede hacerlo... Igual hay que solucionar el tema de SQL mientras siga funcionando así.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con tu propuesta. Por lo único que valdría la pena dejarlo así como está, es, si tendríamos también alguna sugerencia a la hora de responder, dónde podrían convivir ambas recomendaciones al estilo: "Si estas preguntando recuerda que ..." y más abajo "Si estás respondiendo no olvides ..", pero posiblemente sería muy confuso.

Comment: @Patricio creo que sí, que sería más confuso que no tenerlo. Yo lo veo como una "advetencia" (ese naranja de fondo centra bastante la atención), y me molestaría si aparece en todas mis respuestas a una pregunta de SQL.... De todas formas, pregunté para eso, para ver si lo sacamos o alguien piensa algo mejor... Si tuvieses que elegir entre cambiarle el texto o sacarlo, ¿cuál eligirías?

Comment: Es necesario en una pregunta y molesto en una respuesta, pensando que naturalmente debiera haber más respuestas que preguntas, creo que sacarlo es lo mejor.